# Type Mismatch with KFunction1<ServerRequest, Flux<ServerResponse!>>

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, functional-programming, reactor

I am noob to reactive programming, and I was following a tutorial.

I was making user paths but then I met Type Mismatch Error.

```
Type mismatch.
Required: (ServerRequest) -> Mono<out ServerResponse>
Found: KFunction1<ServerRequest, Flux<ServerResponse!>>
```

```
@Bean
fun userRoutes() = router {
    "/user".nest {
        POST("/", userHandler::create)
    }
}
```

```
fun create(serverRequest: ServerRequest) =
        userService.createUser(serverRequest.bodyToMono()).flatMap {
            created(URI.create("user/${it.id}")).build()
        }
```

```
override fun createUser(user: Mono<User>) = userRepository.insert(user)
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought I wrote the code pretty much the similar to one of my working code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the tutorial

Comment: It is a paid tutorial so I don't think I can do that :(

Comment: well i dont know kotlin, so all i can say is that the error message is saying that you are returning a `function` that takes two arguments a `ServerRequest` and a `Flux<ServerResponse>` but it wants you to return a `Mono<ServerResponse>`